# Custom taxonomy filter for media

Tags: custom-taxonomy, media-library

I have the following code already working in the admin for my media library:

```
function atelier_add_iCat_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'iCats',
        'singular_name'     => 'iCat',
        'search_items'      => 'Search iCats',
        'all_items'         => 'All iCats',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent iCat',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent iCat:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit iCat',
        'update_item'       => 'Update iCat',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New iCat',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New iCat Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'iCat',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => 'true',
        'rewrite' => 'true',
        'show_admin_column' => 'true',
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'iCat', 'attachment', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'atelier_add_iCat_taxonomy' );
```

I would like a filter to make sure that images belonging to a certain category are only displayed.

Have tried the following, but it displays the main categories and not the custom taxonomy I have.

```
function atelier_add_image_category_filter() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'upload' == $screen->id ) {
        $dropdown_options = array( 'show_option_all' => __( 'View all categories', 'iCats' ), 'hide_empty' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'orderby' => 'name', );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_options );
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'atelier_add_image_category_filter' );
```

Am I missing something or is there another solution?

Comment: Just a little note,  The taxonomy name should only contain [lowercase letters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Parameters). I don't think that's the solution here, but it might save you some headaches too.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @DaveRomsey - will amend site code

Answer (score 1):

You can add the taxonomy parameter.

```
function add_image_category_filter() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'upload' == $screen->id ) {
        $dropdown_options = array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY', 
            'show_option_all' => __( 'View all categories', 'iCats' ), 
            'hide_empty' => true, 
            'hierarchical' => true,
             // default is cat which wouldn't filter custom taxonomies
            'value_field'       => 'slug',
            'name'              => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY', 
            'orderby' => 'name', );
        wp_dropdown_categories( $dropdown_options );
    }
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'add_image_category_filter' );
```